# Reduce a size of a file(.jar) in unix

Tags: zip, compression

I want to reduce the big file (*.jar) in unix.
i have tried with tar,bzip,gzip and zip commands. but all are same result not compressed much.

Could any one help on this ???

Comment: You know that a JAR file is just a ZIP file (with some special content)?

Comment: Would you settle for several smaller files?

Comment: its a source bundle which is in huge size and so trying to reduce the jar file  size through unix so that it can be transferred fast.

Answer (score 1):

[The JAR file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) is already compressed (using the [Zip algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))).  It is unlikely that you will be able to compress it more than a tiny fraction, if at all.